# Good software design practise

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, software-design

I have a big class, which is used on the user interface of an application. It serves around 20 modules. For only one Module for the time being I need a different formation of number on a `Label`. The applying of formation is programatically only a line of source code. The separation of the cases can be done either by the use of a `boolean` flag variable, or by applying `inheritance`:

By boolean flag variable:

```
class MyClass{

    private boolean isYear;
    ...

    public setValue(){
    ...

    if(!isYear)
     doFormat();

    ...
    }

}
```

The variable `isYear` is set of course externally, when a module serves for year valus is needed.

By applying inheritance I have to create a new class which derives from `MyClass`, i.e. `MyYearClass` and merely override the method `setValue()`. I think in the OO-programming the second approach is recommended, but I have heard also the opinion that in this case it makes the code complicated, more nebulous, less neat and it seems generally an overkill when only one line of code is to be changed. What approach do you consider recommendable?

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. It can be one line now but maybe a lot more later. I agree that overengineering your code is bad but if you feel that the current design will change (and it usually does) you can use a simple design pattern here and there. For your problem (described shortly) I believe you can create a simple `Factory` and have that factory return for you one of the subclasses of `MyClass` you need when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Good design practices **will favour the second method (inheritance)** as it is easier to manage in the long run. When you start adding specific code to a common class, you are opening a can of worms. Maybe not you, but a developer working after you will add another feature, and another feature to the same class and then support becomes a nightmare.

What worries me more is your "I have a big class" quote. Good design principles will tell you to break it apart.

If your class has more than, say, 1000 lines, it's a good candidate for refactoring into specific functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is really better generally. But in your case you have a small class with simple logic. If you know that you are going to change this class a lot and it will become bigger and more complicated, then split it now. Otherwise you might leave it as it is, and postpone the refactoring for a future moment if you feel the class becomes too complicated. Instead, focus on other part of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is the best practice. It might seem a bit superfluous but it is always best to keep your programming as modular as possible. Just imagine if someone else was using your code or you were using it later on and couldn't exactly remember how the MyClass worked but all you wanted to do was use the functionality of MyYearClass.